# dplyr - filter: limit to functions that can be used to generate logical?

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
mtcars["names"]<- rownames(mtcars)
```

Among `mtcars["names"]` are `"Porsche 914-2"` and `"Lotus Europa"`. Naturally, I get

```
> str_detect("Porsche 914-2", "Lotus")
[1] FALSE
> str_detect("Lotus Europa", "Lotus")
[1] TRUE
```

As I expect, I can more generally use the functions `str_detect(names, "Lotus")` to filter `mtcars`:

```
> filter(mtcars, str_detect(names, "Lotus"))
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb        names
1 30.4   4 95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.9  1  1    5    2 Lotus Europa
```

As expected again, I also get

```
> any(str_detect("Pontiac Firebird", as.character(0:9)))
[1] FALSE
> any(str_detect("Fiat X1-9", as.character(0:9)))
[1] TRUE
```

More generally, `any(str_detect(*ANY ELEMENT OF mtcars["names"]*, as.character(0:9)))` always yields the expected result. So I was hoping to be able to use this second function to filter the `mtcars` as well. However, I get:

```
> filter(mtcars, any(str_detect(names, as.character(0:9))))
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb               names
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4           Mazda RX4
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4       Mazda RX4 Wag
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1          Datsun 710
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1      Hornet 4 Drive
5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2   Hornet Sportabout
6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1             Valiant
7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4          Duster 360
8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2           Merc 240D
9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2            Merc 230
10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4            Merc 280
11 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4           Merc 280C
12 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3          Merc 450SE
13 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3          Merc 450SL
14 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3         Merc 450SLC
15 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4  Cadillac Fleetwood
16 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4 Lincoln Continental
17 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4   Chrysler Imperial
18 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1            Fiat 128
19 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2         Honda Civic
20 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1      Toyota Corolla
21 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1       Toyota Corona
22 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2    Dodge Challenger
23 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2         AMC Javelin
24 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4          Camaro Z28
25 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2    Pontiac Firebird
26 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1           Fiat X1-9
27 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2       Porsche 914-2
28 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2        Lotus Europa
29 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4      Ford Pantera L
30 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6        Ferrari Dino
31 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8       Maserati Bora
32 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2          Volvo 142E
Warning message:
In stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I was expecting neither the warning nor the fact that names without numbers remain in the data set, which suggests something is not going as intended.

I get similar behavior with other functions from `dplyr`, such as `mutate`: the first logical condition based on `str_detect` only works as intended, but the second starting with `any(str_detect(` does not.

Can anyone explain why the second condition do not work? Is there a limit to "how deep" the name of the column can be buried inside a function that generates the logical for `filter` (or generates the new data for `mutate`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as.character(0:9)` is vector of length 10. When you check a vector of length 1 (a single string) against this and then wrap in `any` you get what you want. But when you start comparing vector of length 32 to a vector of length 10 you get problems. Instead of using as character how about trying some regex? `filter(mtcars, str_detect(names, "[0-9]"))`

Comment: Thanks. Great solution and your answer helped me better understand how `filter` works :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `as.character(0:9)` is a vector of length 10

```
length(as.character(0:9))
#[1] 10
```

`str_detect` is vectorised over `string` and `pattern` so when you do

```
filter(mtcars, str_detect(names, as.character(0:9)))
```

first 10 values of `names` are matched with `0:9` respectively and then rest of them are recycled again with `0:9` hence you get a warning

> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

What you probably were trying is

```
filter(mtcars, str_detect(names, paste0(as.character(0:9), collapse = "|")))

#    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb          names
#1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4      Mazda RX4
#2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  Mazda RX4 Wag
#3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1     Datsun 710
#4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 Hornet 4 Drive
#5  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4     Duster 360
#6  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2      Merc 240D
#7  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2       Merc 230
#8  19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4       Merc 280
#9  17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4      Merc 280C
#10 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3     Merc 450SE
#11 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3     Merc 450SL
#12 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3    Merc 450SLC
#13 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1       Fiat 128
#14 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4     Camaro Z28
#15 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1      Fiat X1-9
#16 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2  Porsche 914-2
#17 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2     Volvo 142E
```

where

```
paste0(as.character(0:9), collapse = "|") #gives
#[1] "0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9"
```

which is string of length 1 and the same pattern is searched through all the names

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer. I thought I was taking care of that by doing `filter(mtcars, *any*(str_detect(names, as.character(0:9))))` instead of `filter(mtcars, str_detect(names, as.character(0:9)))` as you suggest in your answer. Is the *any()* bit not enough to "de-vectorize" the logical?

Comment: I guess @Adam Sampson's answer below answers that one.

Comment: @MartinVanderLinden `any` returns just one `TRUE/FALSE` for the entire vector.

Comment: Yes, I finally got that through Adam Sampson's answer, thanks.